# How to pass series data to echart option using jquery function

Tags: jquery, charts, bar-chart, echarts

I want a dynamic bar graph using eCharts. I am trying to pass the series value using jquery function but it not accepting.Hre is my code -

```
var data="[{name:'Complete Project', type:'bar', data:[2.0, 4.9, 7.0, 23.2, 25.6, 76.7, 135.6, 162.2, 32.6, 20.0, 6.4, 3.3]},{name:'New Project', type:'bar', data:[2.6, 5.9, 9.0, 26.4, 28.7, 70.7, 175.6, 182.2, 48.7, 18.8, 6.0, 2.3]}]";

getBarGraph(data);
```

and echart initializing code is -

```
       function getBarGraph(data){                
            var dom = document.getElementById("echart-bar");
            var myChart = echarts.init(dom);

            option = null;
            option = {
                tooltip : {
                    trigger: 'axis'
                },
                xAxis : [
                    {
                        type : 'category',
                        data : ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']
                    }
                ],
                yAxis : [{ type : 'value' }],
                series : data
          };

            if (option && typeof option === "object") {
                myChart.setOption(option, true);
            }
       }
```

but no result in browser. So how can i pass the series value ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below code It will work. I added the details within comments.

Out Put Attached.
https://www.screencast.com/t/3yLCOmRVa

```
<!doctype html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <title>ECharts Sample</title>
            <script src="http://echarts.baidu.com/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="echart-bar" style="width: 500px; height: 350px;"></div>
            <script>

            //You need to quote your labels, otherwise will get an unexpected token in JSON
            var series='[{"name":"Complete Project", "type":"bar", "data":[2.0, 4.9, 7.0, 23.2, 25.6, 76.7, 135.6, 162.2, 32.6, 20.0, 6.4, 3.3]},{"name":"New Project", "type":"bar", "data":[2.6, 5.9, 9.0, 26.4, 28.7, 70.7, 175.6, 182.2, 48.7, 18.8, 6.0, 2.3]}]';

            //Call the function 
            getBarGraph(series);

            function getBarGraph(data){
                var dom = document.getElementById('echart-bar');
                var myChart = echarts.init(dom);
                var option = {
                    title: { text: 'ECharts Sample' },
                    tooltip : {
                        trigger: 'axis'
                    },

                     xAxis : [
                        {
                            type : 'category',
                            data : ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']
                        }
                    ],
                    yAxis : [{ type : 'value' }],

                    //Use the JavaScript function JSON.parse() to convert text into a JavaScript object:
                    series: JSON.parse(data),
                };
                myChart.setOption(option);

            }
            </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: @Rifat Tanjir, When you get a chance try above solution It will work. I attached the result screenshot of chart too.

Comment: But Now I am facing a problem when I call function based on my select value in HTML Form it pass the new parameter format into series but the Bar doesn't change, Still when there is no data into series then the bar still looks same . How to solve this, Any Idea.
Thanks @Shivendra_Sing

Comment: Based on select value how you pass the new paremeter.?

Comment: The following line is missing: `<script src="https://fastly.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.7.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>`